# Which tzitzit do I kiss?

Tags: mitzvah, tzitzis, shulchan-aruch

There is a practice among some to kiss the tzitzit at certain points during davening (related questions [abound](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/search?q=kiss%20tzitzis)). The Shulchan Aruch in one place (O"C, 24:5) says that the person should be looking at the tztitzit that are in front of him because they have a certain number of knots etc.
כְּשֶׁמִּסְתַּכֵּל בַּצִּיצִיּוֹת מִסְתַּכֵּל בְּב' צִיצִיּוֹת שֶׁלְּפָנָיו, שֶׁיֵּשׁ בָּהֶם עֲשָׂרָה קְשָׁרִים, רֶמֶז לַהֲוָיוֹת. וְגַם יֵשׁ בָּהֶם ט''ז חוּטִים וַעֲשָׂרָה קְשָׁרִים עוֹלוֹת כ''ו כְּשֵׁם הַהֲוָיָה

However, the O"C in 8:12 also [states](http://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Orach_Chayim.8.12?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) "אִם יֵשׁ לוֹ כַּמָּה בְּגָדִים שֶׁל אַרְבַּע כְּנָפוֹת כֻּלָּם חַיָּבִים בְּצִיצִית. וְאִם לְבָשָׁם כֻּלָּם בְּלֹא הֶפְסֵק וְהָיָה דַּעְתּוֹ מִתְּחִלָּה עַל כֻּלָּם, לֹא יְבָרֵךְ אֶלָּא בְּרָכָה אַחַת"
If one has many four cornered garments, all of them are obligated to have fringes. And if one puts them all on without a break, and has in mind from the beginning about all of them, he only makes a single blessing

This happens to me when I wear both a talit katan and a talit gadol.

When I wear both, I have four tzitziyot in front of me -- which ones am I supposed to hold (and kiss?)? And if I have even more garments, should I be taking the front tzitzityot from only one of them (so that the numbers referenced above hold true) and if so, which one, or all of them because they are all equally important?

Comment: "וְאִם לְבָשָׁם כֻּלָּם בְּלֹא הֶפְסֵק" this almost never happens to me, fwiw.

Answer (score 1):

The tzitzit of the tallit gadol would take precedence because the fulfillment of the mitzvah is more complete in regard to atifah (being wrapped, head and body) See Tur, Orach Chaim 8:2 and Beit Yosef there. See also the Drisha to Tur, Orach Chaim 8:1:1.

> אמר שמואל כל עטיפה שאינה כעטיפת הישמעאלים אינה עטיפה

After the fact, one might have fulfilled by using the tzitzit of the tallit katan, but to start out, it is preferable to use the tallit gadol if you are wearing both.

In terms of consistency, you would want to use the tzitzit from the single garment, not one from an outer garment and one from an inner garment. This relates to a more esoteric concept of the level of makifim that you are associating with.

The two citations from Orach Chaim are not related. 8:12 is dealing with the halachic question of whether one is required to make the blessing for tzitzit more than once for different garments. If you aren't putting them on at the same moment, meaning consecutively with the intention that they all be included in the single blessing, one right after the other, then two blessings are required. This same type of reasoning is used in regard to the blessing for tefillin.

The second citation, Orach Chaim 24:5, is discussing those who follow that particular minhag of gazing at the tzitzit during the recital of the third paragraph of Shema.

Comment: Can you [edit] to include any sources for your first few paragraphs (the ones that actually address the question)? For instance, what does a "more complete" fulfillment even mean and how do you know it applies here? Right now it's just your word, and none of us know you to trust that.

Comment: @DoubleAA Bli neder, when I get a moment. The first part is easy. The second idea will require a little more digging.

Comment: I'm really confused about your last edit. What is it a citation for? You didn't address either of the concerns I mentioned ("what does a 'more complete' fulfillment even mean and how do you know it applies here?") and you also didn't cite anything related to the actual answer of the question, namely, which tzitzit to kiss. All I see is a statement about what Atifa is, though the statement is essentially completely opaque as it defines one technical term in terms of another. What does this show about which tzitzit to take? Why not take all of them, for instance?

Comment: @YaacovDeane I know that the citations are unrelated in content but the first one points to the potential case of wearing multiple fringed garments at the same time. Otherwise, the question is a non-starter.

Comment: The blessing for the tallit gadol is "l'hitatef b'tzitzit". You don't say that over a talit katan. The idea of 'Atifah gamurah' is mentioned in many places as the more complete idea of wrapping in the tzitzit, like in Ohr Zaruah and in the Beit Yosef I mentioned. The Drisha cited mentions in connection with 'Atifah gamurah' that you fulfill with any, but the Atifah gamurah satisfies all views, meaning more complete. This is the same way it is explained in Shulchan Aruch HaRav. Regarding your question about if you take all four front tzitzit, you are not following the minhag.

Comment: @Danno I understand. And in reality, for many, they wear two garments with tzitzit every day. The question about what the significance of multiple tallitot is, relates back to my comment about 'makifim'. In general, tallit and tefillin pertain to two different concepts in seder hishtalshelut. Tallit pertains to the concept of 'Makif' AKA 'Sovev'. That is the idea of being enwrapped. Tefillin pertains to the concept of 'Memaleh', implying 'filling' like dressing within the world. There are different levels of 'Makif', inner and outer. The outer, as discussed, is higher.

Comment: @YaacovDeane the Shulchan Aruch says "עַל טַלִּית קָטָן יָכוֹל לְבָרֵךְ לְהִתְעַטֵּף, אַף עַל פִּי שֶׁאֵינוֹ מִתְעַטֵּף אֶלָּא לוֹבְשׁוֹ". The Ramo is the one who says " וְיֵשׁ אוֹמְרִים שֶׁמְּבָרְכִין עָלָיו עַל מִצְוַת צִיצִית וְכֵן נוֹהֲגִין, וְאֵין לְשַׁנּוֹת " So those who follow the S"A  are doing something wrong?

Comment: @Danno To say l'hitatef, the tallit katan needs to be large enough. Many are not. And the procedure for wrapping is also different. If someone is paying attention to all those details, then what you are saying from Shulchan Aruch is accurate.

Comment: @danno you are right and the OP is wrong. Many Poskim, primarily but not exclusively non ashkenazi ones, think lihitateif is always the correct blessing irrelevant of size or method of wrapping. the op is also confusing "fulfilling more views" with "more complete fulfillment".

Comment: @DoubleAA for talit katan it seemed that there IS a different way of "wrapping" -- וְטוֹב לְהַנִּיחַ אוֹתוֹ עַל רֹאשׁוֹ רָחְבּוֹ לְקוֹמָתוֹ, וּלְהִתְעַטֵּף בּוֹ, וְיַעֲמֹד כָּךְ מְעֻטָּף לְפָחוֹת כְּדֵי הִלּוּךְ ד' אַמּוֹת, וְאַחַר כָּךְ יִמְשְׁכֶנּוּ מֵעַל רֹאשׁוֹ, וְיִלְבְּשֶׁנּוּ

Comment: @Danno There indeed are ashkenazi poskim who say that you only say lihitateif if you actually wrap it around your head, and that's why there is this alternative blessing for when you don't. This opinion isn't help outside of ashkenaz afaik and even within it it's disputed (some reject the other blessing entirely; some say it is for garments that are less than a shiur so it's not too levatala since god did command us about tzitzit).